# How to position divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a custom animation player. Three.js is used for render object and it works perfectly. Problem is to add something like control options on the bottom(like play,pause etc). I'm not sure but probably canvas is rendered as last part of page. There is my code:

```
<body>  
        <div id="playerContainer">
            <div id="renderContainer" style="width:400px;height:300px"></div>
            <div id="controlContainer" style="width:400px;height:30px">
                <input id="rangeBar" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" style="width:400px;height:30px"/>
            </div>      
        </div>      
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
            <script src="jquery.fullscreen-min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tween.js/5/Tween.js"></script>
            <script>    
                container = document.getElementById( 'renderContainer' );
                bar = document.getElementById( 'rangeBar' );
                document.body.appendChild( container ); 
                var scene = new THREE.Scene();
                var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, $('#renderContainer').width()/$('#renderContainer').height(), 0.1, 1000);
                camera.position.z = 5;
                camera.position.y = 0;
                camera.position.x = 0;
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize( $('#renderContainer').width(), $('#renderContainer').height()-30 );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
                var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
                loader.load("model(1).json", function ( obj ) {
                    scene.add( obj );
                    render();
                    },
                    function ( xhr ) {
                        console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
                    },
                    function ( xhr ) {
                        console.error( 'An error happened' );
                    }
                );
                var render = function () {
                    requestAnimationFrame(render);
                    renderer.render(scene, camera);
                    TWEEN.update();
                };
                render();
            </script>
    </body>
```

and the result is: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaU7J.png)

I read something about positions in css(relative and absolute) and tried this as well:

```
<div id="playerContainer" style="position: relative;">
    <div id="renderContainer" style="width:400px;height:300px"></div>
    <div id="controlContainer" style="width:400px;height:30px">
                <input id="rangeBar" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" style="position: absolute;top:400px;width:400px;height:30px"/>
    </div>      
</div>
```

but it works worst. In both solutions playerContainer contains only controlContainer and when I set any height for that element my canvas is still at the bottom. How is it possible to get this hierarchy:

```
<PLAYER>
  <RENDERER/>
  <CONTROL/>
</PLAYER>
```

@UPDATE
I want something like that:

[image]

when:

```
-green - playerContainer
-red - rendererContainer
-yellow - controlContainer
```

Comment: I put there all my code (except `body` tag there is empty `head`). I have model as json file, should I put it there?

Comment: So you want your `#playerContainer` at the bottom of your canvas?

Comment: @nashcheez I edited my post and put there simply image

Answer (score 0):

You have to use javascript to append your `renderContainer` element into the `playerContainer` element after the canvas has been rendered.

However, since you have to append `renderContainer` as the fist child of `playerContainer`, you should use [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).

This code should do the trick:

```
var playerContainer = document.getElementById("playerContainer");

playerContainer.insertBefore(document.getElementById("renderContainer"), playerContainer.firstChild);
```

I have created a fiddle for you. You can see the working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/LvjykL23/